# AngularJS - A simple infinite scroll

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll

I am trying to write a similar small infinite scroll to the one found here: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/

I've been able to display the first 5 pieces of data, however on scroll, the further items are not being displayed.

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed" directive-when-scrolled="loadMore()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: 5">{{ i.Title }}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.items = [
    {
       "Title":"Home"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Contact"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Help"
    },
    {
       "Title":"About"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Our Offices"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Our Locations"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Meet the Team"
    }
    ,
    {
       "Title":"Our Mission"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Join Us"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Conferences"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Tables"
    },
    {
       "Title":"Chairs"
    } 
  ];

    var counter = 0;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({id: counter});
            counter += 10;
        }
    };

    $scope.loadMore();


});


app.directive("directiveWhenScrolled", function () {
  return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('app', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6ggYGZx6scSoJ5PNhj67?p=preview

Comment: have you seen [this](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll)?

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand - Yes i have, it looks good, although it requires me/my application to make another HTTP request to the .JS file and i really want to avoid that as i have enough as it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems. First of all, what is `attr.whenScrolled`? Its undefined. Second one - `limitTo: 5`. You will allways show only 5 elements!

Here you have working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/VszvMnWCGb662azo4wAv?p=preview

What was changed? Your directive is called `directiveWhenScrolled` so call:

```
scope.$apply(attr.directiveWhenScrolled);
```

instead of

```
scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
```

How lets deal with static limit. Change it into variable (remember about defining default value):

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: limit">{{ i.Title }}</li>
```

And now your `loadMore` function should look like this:

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.limit += 5;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found an awesome angularjs ['infinite' scroll solution](https://medium.com/@alimfazeli/lazy-rendering-in-angularjs-ng-repeat-2b5de87e52ee).

What you need to do is just add an [in-view directive](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) in your project and do next stuff:

```js
angular.module('infinitScrollApp', ['angular-inview'])
       .controller('infinitScrollController', infinitScrollController);
       
function infinitScrollController($scope) {
  $scope.limit = 10;
  $scope.items = Array.from(Array(1000).keys());
  
  $scope.loadMore = function (last, inview) {
      if (last && inview) {
          $scope.limit += 10;
      }
  }
}
```

```css
.infinit-scroll-container {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y:scroll
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-inview/3.0.0/angular-inview.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="infinitScrollApp">
    <div class="infinit-scroll-container">
        <ul ng-controller="infinitScrollController">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: limit" in-view="loadMore($last, $inview)">
            {{item}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason that answer get -1?

Comment: I have no idea why this answer get -1. For me this approach works perfectly :)

Comment: Seems I can't get it work...