# How To Make A Infinite Scrollable Table Using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, scrollbar

Here , I want to make a table with infinite scroll of Same entries Using Angular javascript.
What i did so far is , I just made a Simple table with scroll bar using Angular javascript.

The Entries for the table are below.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

var users = [
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Beverages",
        "ProductName": "Steeleye Stout"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Beverages",
        "ProductName": "Laughing Lumberjack Lager"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"",
        "ProductName": "Lakkalik\u00f6\u00f6ri"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Thumpsup",
        "ProductName": "Guaran\u00e1 Fant\u00e1stica"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Fanta",
        "ProductName": "Ipoh Coffee"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Limca",
        "ProductName": "Chang"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Mountain Dew",
        "ProductName": "Chartreuse verte"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Mrinda",
        "ProductName": "Ipoh Coffee"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Pepsi",
        "ProductName": "Chai"
    },
    {
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Name":"Coca Cola",
        "ProductName": "Chang"

    }
];
$scope.users = users;});
```

This is Body of Table.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table border="3px;">
<tr>
<td>CategoryName</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>ProductName</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
<td>{{user.CategoryName}}</td>
<td>{{user.Name}}</td>
<td>{{user.ProductName}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The Style and Cdn of My Code is Below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
table thead {
 display: block;
}
table tbody {
height: 200px;
display: block;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
```

I tried many other ways to make infinite scroll bar but , i am, not getting what i want . I get the desired Output using Jquery https://codepen.io/amar1203/pen/ZEGyRzP but using angular i am not getting the result.

Comment: What is your desired outcome? I don't see anything to do with infinite scrolling? Are you asking how to do it from scratch? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627962/angularjs-a-simple-infinite-scroll

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias wait i am going to share my JQuey Output and i want the same  in angular . https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: That's a link to a blank codepen. It sounds like you just want somebody to tell you how to do it from scratch in AngularJS. Just check the link I shared.

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias sorry My bad bro , i did'nt saved my code at codepen check it now https://codepen.io/amar1203/pen/ZEGyRzP

Answer (score 0):

Use this directive it is good, I have implemented
https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/